# Efficient variable byte iteration over a string in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm reading a large (500MB) binary file in Python and parsing it byte by byte into a Python data structure.  This file represents a sparse data grid.  Depending on the format sometimes I need to read one byte, two bytes, or four bytes at a time.  For bureaucratic  reasons, I'm required to do this in Python rather than C.

I'm looking for runtime efficient mechanisms to do this in Python.  Below is a simplified example of what I'm doing now:

```
with open(filename,'rb') as inFile:
 nCoords = struct.unpack('!i',inFile.read(4))[0]
 for i in range(nCoords):
    coord = (struct.unpack_from('!h',inFile.read(2))[0],struct.unpack_from('!h',inFile.read(2))[0]) # x, y coord
    nCrops = struct.unpack_from('!B',inFile.read(1))[0] #n crops
    for j in range(nCrops):
        cropId = struct.unpack_from('!B',inFile.read(1))[0] #cropId
```

I'm wondering if loading the file from disk into a string, and parsing out the string would be more efficient than reading a few bytes at a time.  Something like:

```
with open(filename,'rb') as inFile:
   wholeFile = inFile.read()
```

But I doubt that using array splicing on `wholeFile` will be more efficient than what I'm already doing.

Is there a runtime efficient mechanism in Python to read a file into a string, then iterate over it a few bytes at a time?  *(I've checked out `StringIO` and it only allows reading a line at a time, not what I want in this case since the whole file is one line).*

Comment: What do you mean by `efficient`? As in memory, or speed?

Comment: @Blender, thanks for the clarification, I mean speed.

Comment: You can try both approaches. Time them: http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html.

Comment: I'd guess that the speed boost would be proportional to the filesize when loading into RAM, as line-by-line would work well for small files, but it'll get slower for larger ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html)

Comment: Whoa, that's pretty awesome! A Python module which does *just* that!

Comment: @Carl: Nope. I've had 2-character answers chosen. Maybe even a 1-character answer.